# How to configure Eclipse to autocomplete using java.util.List and not java.awt.List?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse: Exclude specific packages when autocompleting a class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073913/eclipse-exclude-specific-packages-when-autocompleting-a-class-name)

It's a minor thing, but it drives me nuts that when I type `List` in Eclipse, it always asks me if I mean `java.util.List` or `java.awt.List` when I *never ever* use `java.awt.List`. There are other similar cases with name collisions in my own project and more esoteric standard libraries. Is there a way to configure Eclipse to assume that I mean `java.util.List` unless I go out of my way to specify otherwise?