# Eclipse: Exclude specific packages when autocompleting a class name

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

When auto-completing a class name in Eclipse, e.g. if you type:

`ListI`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

A pop-up menu appears offering you matching class names for completion (which you can select with the mouse or by using the arrow keys:

In this example, I almost certainly want `java.util.ListIterator` and I almost never want `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListIterator` (or anything else from that package).

This particular class will appear in the list frequently (every time I declare a `ListIterator`).  I would like to be able to exclude packages from autocomplete searches, so that `java.util.ListIterator` is auto-completed without the need for a pop-up menu.

Is this possible?

Comment: Oh, it would be great if you could just select the one you do not like and press Delete like in some other programs.  But no ...

Comment: Just completed my answer to address the `java.awt.List` question you mention in the comments.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

`Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Appearance` > `Type Filters`

You should be able to specify there the packages you do not want to see.

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/images/type-filter.png]

See [Java Tips and Tricks](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html)

> To exclude certain types from appearing in content assist, use the type filter feature configured on the `Java > Appearance > Type Filters` preference page.
> **Types matching one of these filter patterns will not appear in the Open Type dialog and will not be available to content assist, quick fix and organize imports.**
> These filter patterns do not affect the Package Explorer and Hierarchy views.

---

[finnw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12048/finnw) (the OP) adds in the comments:

> Now how do you add a single class to this list? I'm not interested in java.awt.List but occasionally I want java.awt.Window or java.awt.Dimension. –

"Type filter" is actually based on **class pattern matching**, meaning if you add:

```
 java.awt.List
```

that class will disappear from the content assist propositions.
If you know all `java.awt.Lxxx` classes are of no interest, you could add

```
 java.awt.L*
```

All other classes from `java.awt` would still be there for the content assist.
With a recent eclipse (I have right now a eclipse 3.6Mx, but this should work for 3.5.x as well), you are not limited to *package* pattern only in the Type Filter.

Comment: It's also case sensitive, which is why when I tried "java.awt.list" it didn't work.

Comment: It's a shame you can't just prioritize certain classes instead of removing them from the list...

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I had to google for this as well even though I'd added some before.  Its a crying shame that someone really thinks this belongs in Appearance instead of, oh, Java->Editor->ContentAssist...

Answer (score 53):

`Window` > `Preferences` > `Java` > `Appearance` > `Type Filters`