# Eclipse content assist Remove hidden classes

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I did at one time configure my Eclipse/Project not to include classes from java.awt when activating content assist (Ctrl+Space).

Now I want to include content from java.awt again but I can't remember where I edited the list of classes to ignore, no I can't remove java.awt from the list to ignore. Anyone who know where that feature is in eclipse 3.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Exclude specific packages when autocompleting a class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073913/eclipse-exclude-specific-packages-when-autocompleting-a-class-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the Preferences dialog.  Search for `ignore`.

This is the tree path:

Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters