# Eclipse code recommendation for Java: how to hide all 'package names'?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse code recommendation for Java: how to hide all 'package names'?

[image]

Like the figure above. After typing one character 's', there's a a large list of package names like **'sun', 'sun.applet', 'sun.applet.resources'**, etc. , and class name like **SecuritiException, String, StringBuilder**, etc. are placed after this large list of package names.

How to always hide all package names like **'sun', 'sun.applet', 'sun.applet.resources'**, etc., in the recommendation list? In other words, all items beside package names like templates, enclosing type members, class names, are shown normally, and all package names like **'sun', 'sun.applet'** are always hidden? Adding type filters is not an option, since package name prefixes would also hide all class name in corresponding packages with those prefixes.

Comment: try to use answer provided in below question .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073913/eclipse-exclude-specific-packages-when-autocompleting-a-class-name

Comment: @SnehalPatel OP specifically said that's not an option.