# Eclipse - auto import java.util classes on ambiguous imports

Tags: java, eclipse, import, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way Eclipse will [auto import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982885/can-eclipse-be-configured-to-automatically-fix-missing-imports) classes from java package as `java.util.List` without the need to choose it explicitly in every class?

(even without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>)

When I write List and eclipse auto import `java.util.List` instead of suggesting irrelevant List as `org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xsdschema.ListDocument.List`

I know I can [exclude by Type Filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073913/eclipse-exclude-specific-packages-when-autocompleting-a-class-name), but I just want specific objects as List to be automatically imported.

[image]

Comment: If you use the content assist or do a refactoring, the import statement is automatically added. In addition, you can do _Organize imports_ on save. But this would require avoiding ambiguities by using _Type Filters_ or/and by restricting visibility of specific types in a specific library.

Comment: @howlger I see in Content Assist (Neon) that it's only for single proposal

Comment: If you write the code statement by statement using the content assist or e. g. doing TDD using _Quick Fixes_ (Ctrl+1), no import statements will be missing. How did it come to the situation that import statements are missing?

Comment: @howlger it's not missing, I just want automatically import `java.util.List` using include, instead excluding the other dozen options

Comment: Do you actually have dozens of type definitions (classes, interfaces or enums) named `List`?

Comment: @howlger Yes, see screenshot in question

Comment: I see. The following five type filters should serve the purpose: `a*.List`, `c*.List`, `o*.List`, `java.awt.*` and `javax.*.List`. However, I would recommend modularizing the code e. g. by using several interdependent projects or using OSGi.

Comment: The IDE learns and recommends to you the frequently used on the top. Apart from that, you have to manually select the appropriate one yourself.

Comment: @MukulBansal it's quite annoying re-selecting List every class

Comment: @user7294900 Have you seen `eclipse Project —> Properties->Java Editor —> Save Actions` tab? Try there `Organize imports checkbox`.

Comment: @yami Thanks, it help to find it first in list, can I auto import it?

Comment: @user7294900 I don't use Eclipse, but as i understand it - whenever you save a file this action occurs. Please let me know if you are happy with that as an answer.

Comment: @yami it's not a complete answer, but it helps in the right direction and maybe it can't be done unless there is a new enhancement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Automatically organise import statements whenever you save**

- Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions.
- Select Perform the selected actions on save (off by default).
- Ensure that Organize imports is selected (on by default).

**Let Eclipse collapse imports in the same package a wildcard (.*) or
   always expand them**

- Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports.
- Change the value of Number of imports need for .* to 0.
- (Optional) Change the value of Number of static imports needed for .* to 0.

**Exclude unwanted packages using Type Filters**

- Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance > Type Filters.
- Click Add… to add a package/class.
- Enter java.awt.List (or java.awt.* if you don’t intend using any AWT classes).

**some these other features**

- **Folding**: By default, Eclipse folds all import statements into one line so your class takes up less space on the screen. You can change this by going to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Folding and deselecting Imports.
- **Sorting**: If you’re really particular about the order of packages, you can go to Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports and define the order of the packages as you want Eclipse to order them. It’s not really worth the effort though so I’d skip it.
- **Compress/abbreviate package names in the Package Explorer** (not in your class but in the view): You can display packages compressed (eg. o~.e~.swt) or abbreviated (eg. org.eclipse.swt.custom becomes {SWT}.custom). Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Appearance and define the settings there. The dialog has decent examples of how to do this.