# Eclipse - Extract local variable replace all occurrences only in scope

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, local-variables

I'm using Eclipse Neon

I have a repeating method calls in a over sized method:

```
 myObj.getStatus()
```

E.g.

```
if (myObj.getStatus() == ONE || myObj.getStatus() == TWO ) {
}
myObj.changeMe();
if (myObj.getStatus() == THREE || myObj.getStatus() == FOUR) {
}
myObj.changeMe2();
...
```

where status can be updated internally between calls

I have only 2 options

- Extract local variable and check the Replace all occurrences only in scope (method) which isn't good (because `getStatus()` isn't effectively final)
- Extract local variable and replace manually each relevant `myObj.getStatus()` call

I finally Extract a method and then Extract local variable and check the Replace all occurrences

Is this the most valid option? or can I replace only in specific context/selected text in eclipse? if not can this be consider as enhancement for eclipse refactoring?

**EDIT**

I was hoping for refactor to the nearest enclosing block similar to JavaScript's `let`

Actually the code is not in same level, yet eclipse replace all occurrences in method

```
if (myState.equals(STATE_ONE){
  if (myObj.getStatus() == ONE || myObj.getStatus() == TWO ) {
  }
  myObj.changeMe();
}
if (myObj.getStatus() == THREE || myObj.getStatus() == FOUR) {
}
myObj.changeMe2();
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third option for that:

1. Make sure the checkbox *Replace all occurrences of the selected expression with references to the local variable* is checked
2. Click ***Preview >***
3. **Uncheck the checkboxes** where the **expression should not be replaced** (in your case, the last two)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was hoping for refactor to the nearest enclosing block similar to javascript's let

Comment: Maybe there should be additional levels for blocks/scopes in the control box tree. But in your example, all four occurrences are not inside the if-statement body and therefore in the same block/scope. There should be one group for each, before and after `myObj.changeMe()`, but how to know that `myObj.changeMe()` changes the value of the extracted variable?

Comment: add an enhancement https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538518

Comment: I have a another question about eclipse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716180/eclipse-auto-import-java-util-classes-on-ambiguous-imports